# Chart from Highfaces dosen't work

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

Why does the code above works and the line chart below dosen't?
Both example are from the bootsfaces.net site.
The Pie Chart is shown correctly but the line chart only the titel is shown.Both share the same bean propertys

```
    <b:row>
        <b:column col-md="6" col-xs="6">
            <hf:chart type="pie" title="Series with individual lists">
                <hf:chartSerie name="Boys" value="#{lineChartBean.boys}"
                    var="point" point="#{point.amount}" tickLabel="#{point.year}"
                    dataLabel="{point.name}: {point.percentage:.1f} % ({point.y})" />

            </hf:chart>
        </b:column>
        <b:column col-md="6" col-xs="6">
            <hf:chart type="line" value="# {lineChartBean.boys}" var="birth"
                xaxisLabel="Years" point="# {birth.amount}"
                tickLabel="# {birth.year}" title="List of Pojos" />
        </b:column>
    </b:row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is simple: you did not remove the empty spaces between # and { in below chart. The spaces originate from the code formatting tool on the highfaces demo, but should not be part of the actual code that you use in your application.

The correct markup in your code should look like this:

```
<hf:chart type="line" value="#{lineChartBean.boys}" var="birth"
            xaxisLabel="Years" point="#{birth.amount}"
            tickLabel="#{birth.year}" title="List of Pojos" />
```